# Scala-How to filter an RDD org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD which needs to be filtered on price. Here is the rdd

```
id      category_id       product_name                               price   
1       2            Quest Q64 10 FT. x 10 FT. Slant Leg Instant U   59.98
2       2            Under Armour Men's Highlight MC Football Clea   129.99
3       2            Under Armour Men's Renegade D Mid Football Cl   89.99
4       2            Under Armour Men's Renegade D Mid Football Cl   89.99
5       2            Riddell Youth Revolution Speed Custom Footbal   199.99
6       2            Jordan Men's VI Retro TD Football Cleat         134.99  
7       2            Schutt Youth Recruit Hybrid Custom Football H   99.99
8       2            Nike Men's Vapor Carbon Elite TD Football Cle   129.99
9       2            Nike Adult Vapor Jet 3.0 Receiver Gloves        50.0
```

I am getting following error

```
scala> val rdd2 = rdd1.map(.split("\t")).map(c => c(3) < 100) 
<console>:44: error: type mismatch; found : Int(100) required: String val rdd2 = rdd1.map(.split("\t")).map(c => c(3) < 100)

df.printSchema()

root |-- id: integer (nullable = true) 
     |-- category_id: integer (nullable = true) 
     |-- product_name: string (nullable = true) 
     |-- price: double (nullable = true) 
     |-- image: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: what is the condition of your filter?

Comment: scala> val rdd2 = rdd1.map(_.split("\t")).map(c => c(3) < 100)
<console>:44: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(100)
 required: String
       val rdd2 = rdd1.map(_.split("\t")).map(c => c(3) < 100)
                                                          ^

Comment: did you remove the header line when you read the file as rdd?

Comment: It was a DataFrame, which I converted into an RDD and added Header using the code below: val rdd = df2.rdd

val data = rdd.map(_.mkString("\t")) 

val header = sc.parallelize(Seq(df2.columns.mkString("\t")))

val rdd1 = header.union(data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply read the file using `sparkContext.textfile` and do the computation as below

```
val rdd1 = sparkSession.sparkContext.textFile("text file location")
val rdd2 = rdd1.map(_.split("\t")).filter(c => !"price".equalsIgnoreCase(c(3).trim)).filter(c => c(3).toDouble < 100)
```

If you already have a `dataframe` then you don't need to convert them back to `rdd` for computation. you can just `filter` on `dataframe` itself

```
val finaldf = df.filter($"price" =!= "price").filter($"price".cast(DoubleType) < 100)
```

Comment: i am getting java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "price" error

Comment: can share the schema of your dataframe? `df.printSchema`

Comment: It's an avro file that i read using spark.read.avro and converted to rdd to perform rdd operations

Comment: Please find the schema scala> df2.printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- category_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- product_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- price: double (nullable = true)
 |-- image: string (nullable = true)

Comment: Hi, giving me this o/p scala> rdd2.take(10).foreach(println)
[Ljava.lang.String;@6667858b
[Ljava.lang.String;@5096ba16
[Ljava.lang.String;@669e0d69
[Ljava.lang.String;@554a10a2
[Ljava.lang.String;@f5b8c5d
[Ljava.lang.String;@6a78c1aa
[Ljava.lang.String;@7c9b7cc9
[Ljava.lang.String;@7951bcf8
[Ljava.lang.String;@2abbeeeb
[Ljava.lang.String;@6621f87

Comment: you should print it like `rdd2.take(10).foreach(array => println(array.mkString(",")))`

Comment: if the answer helped you please accept and upvote :)

Comment: hi, now how can i write the output to a textfile??

Comment: just use `rdd2.map(_.mkString(",")).saveAsTextFile("path to output file")`. :) thanks for the acceptance ;)

Answer (score 0):

Given your `df.printSchema()`, you can filter your table using a query on the column `price`

```
df.filter(df.col("price") < 100).show
```

Comment: I am getting this error <console>:44: error: value price is not a member of String
       val rdd2 = rdd1.filter(item => item.price < 100)
                                           ^